# Excel Looping through a table and deleting a specific cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to loop through a table in excel. The table ranges from (A1: C50). Column A is Serial Number, Column B is income, Column C is Total.

I have a cell D10 which is a random Serial number. I want to loop through the table and check if the serial number in the table corresponds with my serial number in D10 and delete the correspongding income cell for that row. Is it possible by using VBA.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
For x = 1 To 50
  If Cells(x, 1).Value = Cells(10, 4).Value Then
    Cells(x, 2).Value = ""
  End If
Next x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub DeleteIncome()
    Dim serialNumbers as Range, cl as Range, randomSerialNumber as Range
    Set serialNumbers = Range("A1:A50")
    Set randomSerialNumber = Range("D10")

    For each cl in serialNumbers
        If cl.value = randomSerialNumber.value Then
           cl.offset(0,1) = ""
        End if
    Next cl
End Sub
```